# Perform SOAP calls with WS-Trust (ADFS)

Tags: adfs, java-5, ws-trust

I have a huge and old Java 5 application which now should call a webservice from MS-CRM. This is secured with an ADFS and SOAP calls can be done using WS-Trust.

My first (unauthorized) tries with Apache HTTP Components 4.3 (httpcore/httpclient) just have been fine but they only provide HTTP Basic//Digest and NTLM authentication - not WS-Trust.

Is there a library which can perform SOAP client calls from a standalone Java 5 application (no servlet engine or application server) using WS-Trust?

Key requirements:

- Java 1.5
- Only client required
- WS-Trust authentication
- Not-code-generated clients would be preferred as the application doing the calls is somewhat limitating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the popular and robust WS frameworks out there (like Apache CXF and Axis2) support WS-Trust of ADFS. But today it became complicated to make those run in a Java 1.5 environment.

Besides suggesting [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and [Axis 2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) my solution was to use the REST-endpoint of MS-CRM and obtaining the WS-Trust token by simulated a browser-like HTML-form-login.